# Asyncio wrapper around gpiozero Button.wait_for_press() crashes with segmentation fault

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, raspberry-pi, gpiozero

I am trying to create an asyncio wrapper around gpiozero's `Button.wait_for_press` method. This works most of the time but gives `Segmentation fault` randomly.

```py
import asyncio
from gpiozero import Button


def get_gd_input():
    Button(5).wait_for_press()


async def get_input():
    INPUT = ""

    get_gd_input()
    INPUT = "G"

    print(INPUT)


asyncio.run(get_input())
```

Is something wrong in the above code?